# What is guaranteed about objects of type typing.Mapping?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If a function expects a mapping as an argument, which features can the function body legitimately expect it to have?

For example, is this "typesafe":

```py
def make_immutable(sequence_or_mapping: Union[Sequence, Mapping]):
    if isinstance(sequence_or_mapping, Mapping):
        return tuple(sequence_or_mapping.items())  # Ok to assume .items() here?
    else:
        return tuple(sequence_or_mapping)
```

It would also be useful to know where (if anywhere) these expectations are documented.

*Disclaimer* I understand that typing is opt-in and doesn't have the same implications as it would in a strongly-typed language. I'm just wondering if there is an expectation that goes along with something being an instance of `Mapping`.

Comment: They're documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: The docs say "implements the methods specified in the Mapping or MutableMapping abstract base classes" but the links provided don't say which methods they are!

Comment: It's in the table, in the row that says "Mapping" in the first column.

Comment: Found it! Thanks so much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For future reference the link to the table containing the methods is: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes